# How and why This code is Thread Safe..?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

This is the my code..

```
@immutable // This is not a standard annotation .Only for Showing that behavior of Class 
class OneValueCached{
    private final BigInteger lastNumber;
    private final BigInteger[] lastFactors;
    public OneValueCached(BigInteger i,BigInteger[] factors){
        lastNumber=i;
        lastFactors=Arrays.copyOf(factors, factors.length);
    }

    public BigInteger[] getFactors(BigInteger i){
        if(lastNumber==null || !lastNumber.equals(i))
            return null;
        else 
            return Arrays.copyOf(lastFactors, lastFactors.length);
    }
}

@threadSafe // This is not a standard annotation .Only for Showing that behavior of Class 
public class VolatileCachedFactorizer implements Servlet{
    private volatile OneValueCached cache=new OneValueCached(null, null);

    public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponce resp){
        BigInteger i= extractFromRequest(req);
        BigInteger[] factors=cache.getFactors(i);
        if(factors==null){   // ---> line 1
            factors=factor(i);  // --> line 2
            cache=new OneValueCached(i, factors);
        }

        encodeIntoResponse(resp,factors);
    }
}
```

Why class **VolatileCachedFactorizer** is thread according to **Book** But My point is..
**1.  @ Line 1**  if 2 thread coming at same time at that point 1st `thread` check condition and found **factor=null** and 2nd `thread` also check same condition at the same time after 1st `thread`  suspend at line **2nd** and found  **factor=null**
And both will be create new `OneValueCached` Object Then how this code is thread safe..  According to book this is thread safe..

Thank's

Comment: What an annotation is `@threadSafe` ? It's either a typo or not a standard annotation, since the standard naming convention would be `@ThreadSafe`. (same for `@immutable`)

Comment: Just For notice, i know this is not a standard annotation...

Comment: `return lastFactors=Arrays.copyOf(lastFactors, lastFactors.length);` seems weird. It makes a presumably defensive copy of the internal array, but then also re-assigns the internal state to the same copy it hands out. That is no longer defensive or immutable. Actually, this is a compile error because `lastFactors` is final, no?

Comment: Can you include code which compiles? Where have you defined `cached`?

Comment: `cached` is probably `cache`. But what about the `factor` method?

Comment: The main point was at **line 1, line 2** , that what i want to understand, rather then where is code n all, my point is not compiling code.

Comment: @Thilo there is no problem with lastFactors being final, the assignment happens in the constructor and lastFactors was never assigned before.

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy: Now, there is no problem. Code was edited. There was an assignment in `getFactors` before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's thread safe because there is never inconsistency between `lastNumber` and `lastFactors` which could result in incorrect factoring. It makes no guarantees that the minimum amount of factoring will take place: the `OneValueCached` can be created more than once, but that's still thread-safe.

Answer (score 2):

The exact notion of "thread-safety" has not been defined here. What do you expect to happen/not happen for this code to be thread-safe?

1. If you are expecting the state of all objects involved (as far as I can see in this code) to be consistent, then it's thread-safe (as @artbristol explains).
2. If you are expecting a single creation of a `Cache` object when `service` is called concurrently, then it's not thread-safe.

Again, without the definition of thread-safe behavior for this situation we cannot really tell for sure.

Answer (score 0):

This code is thread safe. But I do not think `Array.copyOf()` in the constructor is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is a question asked more than a year ago,I still want to give my explanation.
In fact, this code is adopted from "Java Concurrency in Practice",page 40.The author claims that VolatileCachedFactorizer is a thread safe servlet,for that servlet programme itself is called concurrently by users.So the author means that if the viariable --OneValueCached cache can be read and write by threads consistently,which means will not cause situations such as lastNumber and lastFactors are not matched,then it will be thread safe.Which I am confused is that the book claims only if Arrays.copyOf() function is used,it would be thread safe.But why?Why is Arrays.copyOf() needed?

Answer (score 0):

Qisen, Answering your question, Arrays.copyOf() is needed because otherwise OneValueCache wouldn't be immutable. If you didn't copy the factors when constructing OneValueCache, you would be letting the reference to the array (which until that point is local to the running thread) escape.